# MySQL and SQLAlchemy: getting N recent comments for multiple items

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a query to get the N most recent comments for multiple items.

Currently, I am looping through the items with a query per item:

```
for i in itemIds:
    Comment.query.filter_by(itemId=i).order_by(Comment.id.desc()).limit(3)
```

But this is really slow.

I would like to have a single query that gets all of the comments, but don't know how. I have tried using `union` but haven't gotten it to work. I appears there are issues with MySQL, `order_by`, and `union`. I am trying something to the effect of:

```
a = Comment.query.filter_by(itemId=1).order_by(Comment.id.desc()).limit(3)
b = Comment.query.filter_by(itemId=2).order_by(Comment.id.desc()).limit(3)
u = union_all(a,b)
DB.session.query(Comment).select_from(u).all()
```

But that doesn't work. It complains about 'Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY'.

I'm not a MySQL or SQLAlchemy ninja, and have been banging my head on this for hours.

Help please! Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the SQL version, please see the "Select the top N rows from each group" section in http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

which gives in SQLAlchemy:

```
c2 = aliased(Comment)
query = session.query(Comment).filter(
            session.query(func.count(c2.id))\
                .filter(c2.id >= Comment.id)\
                .filter(c2.item_id == Comment.item_id)\
                .order_by(c2.id.desc())\
                .correlate(Comment)\
                .as_scalar() <= 3)\
    .filter(Comment.item_id.in_(itemIds)).all()
```

Comment: Awesome.. that does it. Thanks so much!